# How Debian manage conflicts on packages names?

Tags: debian-packaging

How Debian manage conflicts on packages names? As example, when there is many packages with the same name on various repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are many packages with the same name, how could APT know they are different? **It can not**. So it will install the one who has the highest version number.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html).

Section 3.1 says every package needs a unique name.  Section 3.2 describes how version numbers are to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apt's **preferences** file to give your repository a higher priority.

```
man apt_preferences
```